# Are group definitions and method includes in TestNG mutually exclusive?

Tags: java, testng

are group definitions and method includes in TestNG.XML files mutually exclusive?

I want to test the methods of my test classes in a specific order, as they depend on each other. For example, the first method saves entities to a database and the second checks, whether the unique constraints of the database table are working (the test is annotated with an expected exceptions tag).

Now, I would also like to test only a certain group of tests. I have annotated all the tests with a group annotation ("db"). However, TestNG still executes these tests as they are specified in the TestNG file to be included (which I need to do in order to run them in a specific order).

Do you have an idea how to get around this problem? I "solved" it by commenting out the tests which I don't want to be executed, but that is tedious.

Thanks.

```
<suite name="xxx_war_1.0-SNAPSHOT" allow-return-values="true">
<test name="PersistenceTestSuite">
    <groups>
    <run>
        <exclude name="testdata" />
        <include name="db" />
    </run>
</groups>
    <classes>
        <class name="xxx.test.TestdataCreator">
           <methods>
                <include name="createTestdata"/>
            </methods>
        </class>
        <class name="xxx.test.ConnectionProviderTest">
            <methods>
                <include name="testGetConnection"/>
                <include name="testTwoConnectionsNotEqual"/>
                <include name="testCloseConnection"/>
            </methods>
        </class>
[...]

public class ConnectionProviderTest {

private Connection connection;

public ConnectionProviderTest() {
}

@Test(groups = "db")
public void testGetConnection() throws UserFriendlySQLException {

    this.connection = ConnectionProvider.getConnection();

    Assert.assertNotNull(this.connection);

} [...]
```

Comment: Are there other mehods in your ConnectionProviderTest class apart from the 3 you are including?

Comment: No, these are all the methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Order of method executions can be maintained by using priority/dependsOnGroups/dependsOnMethods attributes of @Test annotation. so now you can use groups functionality to include or exclude tests. you just need to group your tests based on your feature requirement.
Let me know if this helps you by accepting this as answer.

Comment: Thank you! Will be using the annotation dependsOnMethods in the future.